# ESP8266 NodeMCU Lolin V3 and using Firebase to update its software OTA

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, nodemcu

I want to update software OTA on multiple of my nodemcu devices that are currently sending data to my firebase database. I found this tutorial (https://medium.com/firebase-developers/over-the-air-arduino-firmware-updates-using-firebase-part-1-3e874ad9f93e) for ESP32 and tried adapting it to work with one of my nodemcu however it writes no binary and "gives up". I am not sure why/how to modify the code further. I am currently running core 2.7.4 as upgrading does not allow me to upload code to my nodemcu.

I have attached part of my code below and output I get in serial monitor. I am able to connect to wifi, change my "updatebit", and send data to firebase so there is no issue there.

[image: Serial Monitor Output]

```
#include <Firebase.h>
#include <FirebaseArduino.h>
#include <FirebaseCloudMessaging.h>
#include <FirebaseError.h>
#include <FirebaseHttpClient.h>
#include <FirebaseObject.h>

//#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <FirebaseArduino.h>

#include "Updater.h"
#include "ESP8266WiFi.h"
#include "ESP8266HTTPClient.h"

#define FIREBASE_HOST "..."
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "..."

#define FIRMWARE_URL \
"http://..."
HTTPClient http;

void setup() {
....
}
void loop() {
  if(updatebit==1){
    updateFirmware();
  } else {
  }
}

void updateFirmware() {
  // Start pulling down the firmware binary.

  http.begin(FIRMWARE_URL);
  int httpCode = http.GET();
  if (httpCode <= 0) {
    Serial.printf("HTTP failed, error: %s\n", 
       http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
    return;
  }
  // Check that we have enough space for the new binary.
  int contentLen = http.getSize();
  Serial.printf("Content-Length: %d\n", contentLen);
  bool canBegin = Update.begin(contentLen);
  if (!canBegin) {
    Serial.println("Not enough space to begin OTA");
    return;
  }
  // Write the HTTP stream to the Update library.
  WiFiClient* client = http.getStreamPtr();
  size_t written = Update.writeStream(*client);
  Serial.printf("OTA: %d/%d bytes written.\n", written, contentLen);
  if (written != contentLen) {
    Serial.println("Wrote partial binary. Giving up."); //content length printed in serial 
monitor is 42 but 0/42 bytes are written and it says "Wrote partial binary. Giving up."
    return;
  }
  if (!Update.end()) {
    Serial.println("Error from Update.end(): " + 
      String(Update.getError()));
    return;
  }
  if (Update.isFinished()) {
    Firebase.setInt("updatebit",0);
    Serial.println("Update successfully completed. Rebooting."); 
    // This line is specific to the ESP32 platform:
    ESP.restart();
  } else {
    Serial.println("Error from Update.isFinished(): " + 
      String(Update.getError()));
    return;
  }
}
```

If I add the "s" in http changing from

```
#define FIRMWARE_URL \
"http://..."
```

to

```
#define FIRMWARE_URL \    
"https://..."
```

I get "HTTP failed, error: connection failed" in serial monitor

Comment: only httpCode 200 is sucess

Comment: Yes i guess so?

Comment: you have `if (httpCode <= 0) {`

Comment: ah I should change it too httpCode!=200

Comment: adding the s in http makes no difference now as I never get 200

Comment: yes that is the true problem. solve that

Comment: I am really not sure how. I tried only running the sketch from the link below under the heading "Fingerprints - secure but annoying" but I still don`t get HTTP_CODE_OK.
https://maakbaas.com/esp8266-iot-framework/logs/https-requests/

Comment: and what error code do you get?

Comment: -1, connection failed. I am using this tool to create the fingerprint (https://www.grc.com/fingerprints.htm). I am using ("96 84 07 DF 0B 1C F6 58 14 DF D7 33 35 57 51 9B 15 4D 8C E7"). My host is just like in example https://api.github.com

Comment: you need `http.begin(client, FIRMWARE_URL);` where client is  `WiFiClientSecure`. (what error code did you get before you changed http to https?)